# How to use a simple code determine actions for an array of square images

Tags: android, image, onclick, action, onclicklistener

I'm starting to learn about Android application development and so I'm working on some small apps to exercise programming and better understand some stuff.

The situation is as follows:

I have 25 square images as a 5x5 array, and I want to specify a different action for clicking on each one.

I declared the images IDs as matrix elements:

```
square11, square12, ... square15
square21, square22, ... square25
  ...      ...            ...
square51, square52, ... square55
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.square11:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.square12:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.square13:
            //do something
            break;
        case R.id.square14:
            //do something
            break;
        //and all other cases...
    }
}
```

But clearly it's not working. Am I missing something about this `OnClickListener`?

Probably it's a newbie's question, but I hope someone can help. I really looked at other code, but they didn't seem to help.

The thing is, do you know what am I doing wrong? And better, do you know if there is a better and cleaner way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Best regards,

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

Do you call these views' setOnClickListener method?

I think using [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and [`AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)is a better way to do this.